# Split XML into different XML using xslt with different number of tags

Tags: xml, xslt

**This is a sample xml that I have to break into multiple files.**
I had tried many ways using result-document and group, but in all example split was equally distributed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sample>
   <A>
      <para>A A A A A A A</para>
   </A>
   <B>
      <para>B B B B B B B</para>
      <child1level1>
         <para>first child first level</para>
         <child1level2>
            <para>second level child</para>
         </child1level2>
      </child1level1>
      <child2level1>
         <para>second child first level</para>
      </child2level1>
   </B>
   <C>
      <para>C C C C C C C</para>
   </C>
   <D>
      <para>D D D D D D D</para>
   </D>
   <G>
      <para>GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</para>
      <child1level1>
         <para>first child first level</para>
         <child1level2>
            <para>second level child</para>
         </child1level2>
      </child1level1>
      <child2level1>
         <para>second child first level</para>
      </child2level1>
   </G>
   <E>
      <para>E E E E E E E E E</para>
   </E>
   <F>
      <child1level1>
         <para>first child first level</para>
         <child1level2>
            <para>second level child</para>
         </child1level2>
      </child1level1>
      <child2level1>
         <para>second child first level</para>
      </child2level1>
      <para>F F F F F F F F F</para>
   </F>
   <G>
      <para>GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</para>
   </G>
   <H>
      <para>H H H H H H H</para>
   </H>
   <I>
      <para>I I I I I I I</para>
   </I>
   <H>
      <para>H H H H H H H</para>
   </H>
</Sample>
```

I have to split the main XML based on group :

- ABCD
- EF
- G
- H
- I

> *In this XML G & H is appearing 2 times so i have to consider them as different groups.

Output1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<split>
   <A>
      <para>A A A A A A A</para>
   </A>
   <B>
      <para>B B B B B B B</para>
      <child1level1>
         <para>first child first level</para>
         <child1level2>
            <para>second level child</para>
         </child1level2>
      </child1level1>
      <child2level1>
         <para>second child first level</para>
      </child2level1>
   </B>
   <C>
      <para>C C C C C C C</para>
   </C>
   <D>
      <para>D D D D D D D</para>
   </D>
</split>
```

Output2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<split>
   <G>
      <para>GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</para>
      <child1level1>
         <para>first child first level</para>
         <child1level2>
            <para>second level child</para>
         </child1level2>
      </child1level1>
      <child2level1>
         <para>second child first level</para>
      </child2level1>
   </G>
</split>
```

Output3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<split>
    <G>
        <para>
            GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
        </para>
    </G>
</split>
```

These are just 3 output file. Other are same in this way. Output files should also have a root tag, I have used split tag as a root tag.

Comment: You will need to show the results you want and explain in more detail what determines to which group/file an element belongs, is that the element name or the `para` value? Also `H` also appears twice, so please take your time to edit the question and show us the result files you want to create for that sample data.

Comment: Are the names of elements you want to put into a group (like `ABCD`) known when you write the stylesheet?

Comment: No. `ABCD` means there is a output file for tag A,B,C,D

Comment: You have not explained what determines to which group an element belongs, if you want to put `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` elements into a group, does that hold for all elements of these names, or only for adjacent? What happens for `<A>...</A><G>...</G><B>...</B>`, do you want to put the `A` and the `B` into a single file?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve that might be using `group-starting-with="*[local-name() = $start-group-with]"` where the parameter is defined as a sequence of element names `<xsl:param name="start-group-with" as="xs:string+" select="'A', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I'"/>` to start a group:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="start-group-with" as="xs:string+" select="'A', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I'"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="*[local-name() = $start-group-with]">
            <xsl:result-document href="split-group-{position()}-key-{local-name()}.xml">
                <Split>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </Split>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That would of course group `A` elements with any elements following before a 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I' follows, but you haven't precisely described what are the criteria, for your example input that would group the adjacent `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` elements together, as `E` and `F`, as well as putting each `G`, `H` and `I` into its own group/file.